# Выборка из бд при связи ' многие ко многим '

Tags: sql

Допустим есть у меня 2 таблицы : tbl1 (id,name)  и tbl2(id,info) . Что бы их связать я использую таблицу tbl3(id,id1,id2) где id1=id из таблицы tbl1 , так же и id2 . Собственно вопрос заключается в том как мне выбрать связанные записи .

Comment: А зачем третья таблица? Может быть такая ситуация, что info не принадлежит ни одному name?

Comment: Что значит "зачем"? Это называется устранением связи М-М путем замены двумя связями М-1, N-1.

Comment: Да я это понял. Но возможно <Tpy> это и ненужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

совсем не так. это даже синтаксически неверно соединять tbl3 дважды под одним именем.

```
 select tbl1.name, tbl2.info 
 from tbl3
      join tbl1 on tbl1.id=tbl3.id1 
      join tbl2 on tbl2.id=tbl3.id2
```